# slideToggle() chose first state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a little website on [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/tobiasglaus/pen/RKKdqy)

As you can see, the box, where you can chose your favourite color is opened, when u visit the site. But I'd like to reverse it, so it's closed and you have to open it up.

```
$('#expandcolors').click(function() {
    $('.colors').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('transform');
  });
```

This is my slideToggle() to make it work.
Any way to reverse that?

Comment: So add the class to start....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try calling what you have inside the click function at the beginning

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  isSavedColor()

  var toggleBox = function(){
    $('.colors').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('transform');
  }  

  $('#expandcolors').click(function() {
   toggleBox();
  });

 toggleBox();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `display:none` to `colors`

```
<ul name="colors" data-for="colors[]" class="colors" style="display:none;">
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RKgrwZ

Answer (score 0):

use :

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  isSavedColor()
 $('.colors').hide();
  $('#expandcolors').click(function() {
    $('.colors').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('transform');
  });
 })
```